# how to handle an 'auto-now' field in a django form?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-3.x, django-1.8

In one of my django models, I have a field like this:

```
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I thought, when creating a ModelForm for this model, I could just skip this field, and Django would populate it automatically.

My ModelForm:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ['text', 'name', 'description'] # notice - modified field not included -
            # should not be shown to the user
```

But, even though it didn't show up in the form, when submitting, when creating a new object, I got an exception:

```
IntegrityError at /url/ - null value in column "modified" violates not-null constraint
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Do you exclude it in your modelform? or is it shown to the user

Comment: You'll need to provide more details - model, view, form, etc. There shouldn't ever be a null value in that field to begin with, so something is odd.

Comment: Does that happen when you create an object? Then you have to set `auto_now_add` to `True` as well.

Comment: @KlausD. That was the problem. If you submit it as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: You should provide the related code required to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto_now field is not populated automatically in such a case.

You need to use auto_add_now, so the field definition looks like this:

```
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then, django will add the date automatically if the field is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to provide a default value to the field.
This can be done as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
modified = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```